# Unable to retrieve RSSI values from BLE nordic thingy:52

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I managed, through the Nordic library for Android `thingylib` ([github](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Nordic-Thingy/tree/master/thingylib)) , to connect to thingy52 and receive in the callback listener `ThingyListener`  the information about the device (e.g. `onGravityVectorChangedEvent`, `onAccelerometerValueChangedEvent`, `onGyroscopeValueChangedEvent`, and so on...).

What I can't do (and I can't find how to do) is how I can get the information about the connection with the device, exactly the RSSI values.

Using the [BluetoothLeScannerCompat](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-Scanner-Compat-Library), inside the `onBatchScanResults` scan callback, I detect the thingy52 bluetooth device, and their RSSI value, but if I set a high scan frequency, for example `.setReportDelay(10)`, it almost always does not detect devices.

How I made scan:

```java
private void startBLEScan() {
        // set scan
        ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .setReportDelay(10) // set frequency
                .setUseHardwareBatchingIfSupported(false)
                .build();

        // filter scan by uuid
        List<no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18.scanner.ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(ThingyUtils.THINGY_BASE_UUID)).build());

        // start scan, this will trigger the scanCallback
        BluetoothLeScannerCompat scanner = BluetoothLeScannerCompat.getScanner();
        scanner.startScan(filters, scanSettings, scanCallback);
    }

    private final ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(@NonNull List<ScanResult> results) {
            super.onBatchScanResults(results);

            for(ScanResult result : results) {
                result.getRssi(); // read RSSI values
            }
        }
    };
```

My need is to get at a frequency of `10Hz`, or `100Hz` the RSSI value of the nordic thingy52, which I can't get from the `ThingyListener` events.

How can I do it? 
Thank you in advance.

Example of my ThingyListener:

```java
  private ThingyListener mThingyListener = new ThingyListener() {


        @Override
        public void onGravityVectorChangedEvent(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, float x, float y, float z) {
            // Here I got the data from device... but no RSSI value

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I finally solved in this way:**

I don't use the `ScannerCompact`, but the `BluetoothGATT`:

when i link the nordic to the `ThingyLibSdkManager` i also link it to a `GATT`:

```java
ThingyListenerHelper.registerThingyListener(getApplicationContext(), mThingyListener, device);
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), true, gattCallback);
```

with that, inside the `mThingylistener` now i can request the `rssi`:

```java
     @Override
        public void onGyroscopeValueChangedEvent(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, float x, float y, float z) {

            collectedData.put("onGyroscopeValueChangedEvent_x", x + "");
            collectedData.put("onGyroscopeValueChangedEvent_y", y + "");
            collectedData.put("onGyroscopeValueChangedEvent_z", z + "");

            // request rssi from gatt
            mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
        }
```

now, in async way, you will recieve the callback inside `mBluetoothGatt`:

```java
   @Override
        public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
// do some stuff
}
```